# Redeclaring identifier in nested block in C

Tags: c, pointers, scope, initialization

I have a pointer to an array of integers in a main function to which I assign a block of memory dynamically allocated so that I have a 2D matrix.

Something like:

```
int (*b)[m] = malloc(m*m*sizeof( ... etc ...
```

But I then need to redeclare (flatten out) this matrix in a nested block, within which I first simply used the same identifier (out of sheer laziness perhaps):

so in the nested scope:

```
{
    int *b = (int *) b;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Then I call a function inside that nested scope with the new local b, but it segfaults!
However if within the same nested block I do this:

```
{
    int *d = (int *) b;
    int *b = d;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Just because I use a temporary new d variable and then redeclare b locally initializing it to d, everything works perfectly as expected! So I seem not to be able to declare and initialize a variable
with the same name (shadow) as in the outside scope.

Any clue as to why?

Comment: You want `b` to mean two different things in the same declaration. C simply does not permit it.

Comment: Don't add corrections to comments, [edit] your post to clear things up

Answer (score 0):

```
int *b = (int *) b;
```

In this, both instances of `b` refer to the same variable. You are attempting to initialize a variable with the uninitialized version of the same variable. You should use (at least intermediately) a different name to avert this issue.
This is exactly what you are doing in the second snippet.

Answer (score 0):

**In the first snippet,**

```
{
    int *b = (int *) b;  // this RHS `b` refers to the LHS `b`
    ...
    ...
}
```

you've already defined `b`, which shadows the outer scope `b`, and using the inner `b` to initialize itself (which is basically useless). That's why any further use (since it's a pointer type, attempt to de-reference it is essentially attempt to de-reference invalid memory, which invokes undefined behaviour) is problematic.

**For the second snippet,**

```
{
    int *d = (int *) b; // this is the outer scope 'b'
    int *b = d; // now there is an inner scope b
    ...
    ...
}
```

while assigning to `d`, `b` is the outer scope `b`, next when you define the inner scope `b`, the value of the outer `b` is assigned to the inner scope `b`.